# Missing error when assigning locally to a variable that doesn't exist locally but does globally

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

For a Shiny project I'm using global variables. I'm constantly making the error of using <- where I should be using <<-. But what's crazy is that R doesn't throw an error when trying to assign to a local variable that doesn't exist if that variable does exist in the global environment.

Is this a bug or is there some reason the bbb$bbb assignment here doesn't throw an error like the ccc$ccc assignment does?

```
aaa <- list(aaa="old")
bbb <- list(bbb="old")

f = function(x){
    aaa$aaa <<- x
    bbb$bbb <- x
    ccc$ccc <- x
}
f("new")
#Error in ccc$ccc <- x : object 'ccc' not found

aaa
#$aaa
#[1] "new"

bbb
#$bbb
#[1] "old"

ccc
#Error: object 'ccc' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but expected behavior.

The [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) says:

> 3.4.4 Subset assignment
>
> Assignment to subsets of a structure is a special case of a general
>   mechanism for complex assignment:
>
> ```
> x[3:5] <- 13:15
> ```
>
> The result of this command is as if the following had been executed
>
> ```
> `*tmp*` <- x
> x <- "[<-"(`*tmp*`, 3:5, value=13:15)
> rm(`*tmp*`)
> ```

So, in the first step a copy of the global list `bbb` is made into a local variable `*tmp*`. Then, the subset assignment happens and the result is assigned to a (new) local variable `bbb`, which is lost after the function return.

PS: Side effects are bad and should be avoided. Don't use global variables. Functions should be passed input as parameters and return all output (except plots and files).

Comment: So you're saying that for ccc$ccc the error gets thrown by `*temp*` <- x; but for bbb$bbb that's not an error because it's found in the global environment?

Comment: In Shiny, when the user inputs some data on a web page, I get control inside an observeEvent() function inside a server() function. Since I want to save the data there's really no choice but to assign it to a global and then save the global to a file. When the observeEvent() returns it goes back to the server() and I lose control, so there's nowhere to return(the_data) to.

Comment: Yes to the first comment. I don't use shiny but I doubt that it requires bad programming practices.